# SP online - Chrome error on page creation using SP UI "site can't be reached"

Tags: sharepoint-online, error

Company has online site collections, previously had the ability to create pages in chrome. 
Site Contents > Pages > Files Tab > New Document

As of last week I'm getting generic error of when taking same steps to do a simple page creation: 
This site can’t be reached. The connection was reset.

Really seems like a firewall restriction change but IT claims no changes made. Yes still works in I.E.
Anyone with similar issues? Is it SP or firewall restriction?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First try clearing the cache and cookies from chrome then try this

type   chrome://net-internals  in the search box and press enter
on the left side scroll down to DNS and left click..
Right side first line click the button marked  Clear Host Cache
on the left side, left click on   Sockets
Right side, click the buttons marked  Close idle sockets.
Flush Socket Pools

Close the tab and restart chrome..
Let me know